# Github API: how to view open commits on a specific branch?

Tags: github-api

I am looking for functionality in the github api, to see if there are still open commits on specific branch.

With open commits, I mean all commits that aren't yet merged with the default branch.

I tried to use the "list branches" api (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-branches), but this doesn't return any information on commits.